# Make visual studio ALWAYS have a relative path for references?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I add some reference that is not in the current directory of the project it makes it an absolute path. So then we have to edit the project file and edit it to be relative. Being a group of about half a dozen developers someone always forgets to do this on a regular bases (especially when setting up a project with a lot of references).

Is there a way to make the paths ALWAYS relative? I don't see an option in settings. We can't be the only developers who need relative paths.

Any suggestions or solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Are the references source controlled as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your references in the current directory structure of the solution/projects to take advantage of this default feature. For example, if you have a structure like this:

```
\FolderA\FolderB\References\abc.dll
\FolderC\my.sln
\FolderC\Project\my.csproj
```

... then VS appears to not be able to determine correct relevancy.

You should (and this is where I was going with source controlled references), consider a structure like this:

```
\FolderC\my.sln
\FolderC\References\abc.dll
\FolderC\Project\my.csproj
```

... this lets VS understand all paths being used for the project and allows it to use relative paths.

I would really recommend adding the references to source control (it's usually not a lot of disk space, really) as it can save you from other versioning issues as well.

Disclaimer: this is from observation, I can't find anything from MS documenting it.